# How do I allow only 1 col in datagridview editable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

I want to enable only two columns in the DataGridview to be able to edit. The others should not be allowed to edit. Further I am not directly linking to datasource.

```
Public Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        table_class.table.Columns.Add("Subject", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table_class.table.Columns.Add("Date Assigned", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
        table_class.table.Columns.Add("Date of Submission.", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
        table_class.table.Columns.Add("Date of Completion", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
        table_class.table.Columns.Add("Done", Type.GetType("System.Boolean"))

        DataGridView.ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView.Columns[4].ReadOnly = False

        DataGridView.DataSource = table_class.table

    End Sub
```

Comment: `I am not directly linking to datasource`.  But you are setting a DataSource.

Comment: See whether something like this could work: `dataGridView1.Columns.OfType(Of DataGridViewColumn)().ToList().ForEach(Function(c) c.ReadOnly = True) dataGridView1.Columns(4).ReadOnly = False`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this:

```
DataGridView.ReadOnly = True
```

Try this:

```
        For Each DgvCol As DataGridViewColumn In DGV.Columns
            Select Case DgvCol.Name
                Case "Col1","Col2" 'Can Edit

                Case Else
                    DgvCol.ReadOnly = True 'cant edit
            End Select
        Next
```

Edited to include a second condition in first case to show multiple column exclusions

Comment: What's this DgvCol??

Comment: its a variable assignment for DataGridViewColumn in your DataGridView

Comment: Case "Col1","Col2" 'Can Edit

What to write for the case??

Comment: @tejasgupta You write the name of the columns in your DataGridView that you wnt to be editable, the case else will be read only.

Comment: And, dgvCol will be table_class.table for me??

Comment: Kindly help me out.

Comment: maybe programming just isnt your thing

Comment: here is the declaration `DgvCol As DataGridViewColumn`

Answer (score -1):

```
for i=0 to  DataGridView.Columns.count-1

if i<=1 then 
DataGridView.Columns(i).readonly=false
else
DataGridView.Columns(i).readonly=true
end 

next
```